# Updating outer for loop based on inner loop

Tags: java, loops

My problem is simple. In my below code I have used two for loops for some operation on an array. And I have to update outer for loop for I to start from where it finished in the inner for loop for `j`. So if in the inner for loop `j=3` so `k=3+1` and so the upper for loop must be `i=4`. But instead of that in the upper for loop it sequentially counts `i=0,1,2,3.....`

How to make it work like I described ?

```
int k = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = k; i < n; i++) {
    int d = arr[i];
    sum++;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (arr[j] > d && arr[j] < d + 4) {
            sum++;
        }
        if (arr[j] > d + 4) {
            k = j;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? Please give your variables more descriptive names and indent your code correctly

Comment: @prajeeshkumar please if you're going to edit a question, fix all the issues while doing so (i.e. code formatting, grammar, tags, etc) don't do minor edits

Comment: It is a problem in hackerrank. What i want to do is My outer loop should get the value of k that i am setting in the inner loop. int i should start from where inner variable k left off. So for the 1st iteration i=0. In the inner loop int k gets 3. So in the next iteration i should start from 3 not 1.

Comment: The outer loops i=k will only be set in the beginning, that is why its called initialization.  Once the loop starts it wont be executed again, so if you want to assign the k value to i, you should do it inside the loop.

Comment: The main thing is in my code the outer loop should get (every time it runs) the value k i set in the inner loop. So from the start : 1st iteration: i=0, k=3, So 2nd iteraion must be: i=3. But instead it just runs outer loop like i=1,2,3,4,5 etc and not updated by the value of k in inner loo. I have seen it while debugging the code.

Comment: Open IDE type Ctrl+A and Backspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second if statement Just change

```
k=j
```

to

```
i=j
```

and you are good to go

Comment: That did it. Thanks you. But what was the problem with k ? An explanation will be welcomed :)

Comment: k is just a value that was used to set i. I was the variable that was controlling the outer loop. eg the loop is i=0, then i=1, then i=2 until i=n. so if you set i=3 (lets say j=3) in the inner loop, when you go back to the outer loop, it increments i by one and then continues. but setting k = j does nothing to affect the loop since k was only used once. Does that make sense?

Comment: problem with `k` is that its updated value is never used. Since `int i=k;` will excecute only once, so its better to update `i` instead of `k` as `i` is looping variable not `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you change k in inner loop it never changes the range of i, it always will be 0,1,2,3..... Instead of that you could use a while loop and add a counter in condition. 
For example:

```
 int i = 0;
 while(i < 10){
      i = i+1;
      if(i == 10){
          i = i - 1;
      }
 }
```

Now the condition is changing.

Comment: if you assign a different value to i inside the for loop, it will be reflected in the next check.  So if your loop condition is i<n and n is 100 and you assign 101 to i then the loop won't execute again